# Multiple threads with libmodbus?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety

I'm confused about libmodbus (http://libmodbus.org/) regarding the thread-safety.

I have a program, which works as a Modbus client. I have 5 modbus devices (server), from which I want to read some values.
Currently I programmed a function, which I call in my main(). In this function I have an array with 5 modbus_t instances and with a FOR loop I establish the connection to the servers and read the values - one after another.
It is possible to use the libmodbus in threads so I can establish and read the values simultaneously or not? 
Some websites say 'yes', some say 'no'...

Andre

Answer (score 3, accepted):

libmodbus does not document whether it is threadsafe or not, so this has been determined by looking at the source code:

- You cannot share a `modbus_t` between threads, a `modbus_t` instance is not thread safe.
- You can have many threads each operating on different instances of a `modbus_t`.
- The creation of a `modbus_t` instance is thread safe.

If you need to share a `modbus_t` instance across threads, you need to provide your own locking in order to ensure only one of your threads access that instance concurrently.

Comment: Is it possible to connect many clients (modbus_t) to one server?
I'm trying to create many threads to connect to the same controller, each with its own instance, but it seems that only the last one connected can communicate.
Is ModBus Protocol allowing more than one client on the same server?
Does libmodbus allow multi-connection to the same server?